# Is there a best-practice for looping "all the way through" an array in C++?

Tags: python, c++, c, arrays, for-loop

In Python, one can compare each element of an array with the "next" element (including the last element with the first element) with the following code:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3]
for i in range(-1, 3):
    if a[i] + 1 >= a[i+1]:    
        print a[i], 'works'
```

The output:

```
3 works
0 works
1 works
2 works
```

If I want to compare the first element of an array with the second, the second with the third, etc., **and finally the last with the first**, I can do so with just a loop in Python.

Can I do this in C++? Can I loop though elements in this manner whilst staying entirely in one loop? To further illustrate what I mean, here is some C++ code that has the same functionality as the above Python code.

```
int a[] = {0, 1, 2, 3};
std::cout a[3] << std::endl;
for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    std::cout << a[i] << std::endl;
```

It has the same output. My point is, for certain algorithms, I'd have to manually duplicate the contents of my `for` loops for certain steps. For example, if I want to see if the first element equals the second, the second the third, etc., and finally if the last equals the first, I'd have to manually add this step after or before my `for` loop. ---`if (a[0] == a[3]) foo();`

Is this what I am supposed to do in C++? I am quite new to it and I don't want to get rooted in bad practices.

Comment: You can overload the `[]` operator for vectors or lists so that if given a negative number, x, it will run `[size-x]` so that you could do the same thing you're doing in Python...

Comment: "In Python, one can compare each element of an array with the "next" element […] with the following code:" ummm, no?

Comment: @nonchip Sorry, I fixed the post now.

Comment: I want to compare the first element with the second? This is how you compare elements in C++: for(int i = 0; i < ar.length; i++){if(ar[i] == ar[i+1]){cout<< ar[i] << "works" <<endl; else cout<< ar[i+1] << "works" <<endl;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for (int i=3; i<(3 + size_of_array); ++i)
    std::cout << a[i % size_of_array] << '\n';
```

Comment: Thank you. This is very cool because it is so universal --- I can use it in almost any language!

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::begin()` and `std::end()` algorithm.

```
int a[3]={1,2,3};
for( auto x=end(a)-1; x>=begin(a); --x){
    cout<<*x<<endl;
}
```

The above code outputs `3 2 1`, the revrese order of the array `a`. Have a look at `[begin()][1]`.

Comment: The question doesn't ask how to iterate through an array in reverse order. It's asking how to iterate forward, and then when it gets to the end, he wants to start back at the beginning.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley The question did!

Comment: He's asking how to compare adjacent elements and the last one with the first.